# I have problems positioning text into a image

Tags: css, thumbnails, css-position

I'm having problems because when i'm positioning text into a message, appears an empty space below.

This is the image:

http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/6513/lllmm.jpg

And this is the CSS code i'm using. I don't know where the mistake is.

```
    .thumbnail2{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.thumbnail2 img{
    width:100%;
        height:auto;
}
.thumbnail2 h1{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top:-90px;
    left: 0;
    padding-left:5px;
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.thumbnail2 h1 span{
    font-size:34px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    line-height:40px;
}
.thumbnail2 h1 a{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

This is the HTML / PHP (i'm using it in Wordpress):

```
<div class="post">
                    <div class="thumbnail2">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('grandote'); ?>
                        <h1><span><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span></h1>
                    </div>
                        <div class="excerpt2"><p><?php echo get_excerpt(280); ?></p></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I've gathered what you want is to display the text on top of the thumbnail.

You should give `.thumbnail2` `position: relative` and `.thumbnail2 h1` `position: absolute`. This would do the trick, afterwards you'll just have to locate the h1 tag in the right place, this time when his position is relative to his parent `div` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a negative margin to your relatively positioned element:

```
.thumbnail2 h1{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top:-90px;
    left: 0;
    padding-left:5px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

    margin-bottom: -90px; // This should fix it
}
```